# Create Python Virtual Environment in a Specific Directory

Tags: python, conda

I have Anaconda and I've been playing around with setting up virtual environments since I have scripts that I need to run that have been written in Python 2 and Python 3. I want to be able to activate my Python 3 virtual environment in a specific directory - ie Python 3 will only run in that directory and all other directories will remain at the default Python 2 that I have set in Anaconda. My problem is that every time I try to activate a new environment, it changes the version of python used everywhere on my machine instead of just in the one directory that I want. Is it possible to create a virtual environment that is limited to a specific location?

I've tried the following:

```
conda create --prefix=testEV1 python=3.5
source activate testEV1
```

and this changes my version of python everywhere in my workspace to 3.5.

Comment: It seems that you have some misconception about virtual environments. Just open a second Anaconda shell and activate a different environment. The environment has nothing to do with the folder structure on your disk, but with the current shell/prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You only have a single default Python installation in effect at any one time.

Once you're done using one virtualenv you can use `deactivate` to go "back" to the standard, physical default Python installation.

Or you can use different command sessions with different virtual environments activated in each session.

Or you can explicitly invoke one version or another of Python from the command line each time, rather than just using the currently active-by-default one.

Comment: Just watch out with explicitly invoking a different version of Python that isn't from the active environment, there may be environment variables set by the activation of the environment to which the alternate Python belongs that affect its behavior. In many cases, this won't be a problem, but then you'll find yourself in that corner case... :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to autoactivate a conda environment when entering a specific directory.

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5179

BUT, it doesn't change the fact that `source activate xxx` affect your shell/prompt instead of your directory structure. You can still manually activate an environment and it will still affect your whole prompt.